# unable to remove border when i have an iframe within an iframe for IE

Tags: html, css, iframe, border

i have an iframe nested inside another iframe, and for both iframes i have these attributes:

```
frameBorder="0" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" scrolling="no"
```

Ive also tried:

```
style="border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"
```

It seems that no matter what I try, the border of the inner iframe keeps showing, as well as the padding within the inner iframe. This is also only the case for IE (v. 8), for firefox it works fine and shows no borders.

Is there any way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use frameborder="0" attribute:
**<iframe frameborder="0" src="..." />**
Unfortunately, do not know, how to set this using CSS.

Comment: I had to use frameBorder with a capital B for it to work with IE11

Answer (score 1):

Capitalize the letter B in "frameborder"

```
<frameBorder="0" ... >
```

It's an IE thing...

Answer (score 0):

I've spent so much time busting my head over this one :)

If you have not defined any values for the `DIV` in which your `IFRAME` is located, a border appears by default. I usually put my `IFRAME`s in the body section of a separate HTML file. I add this line of code in my CSS file and boom! Problem solved.

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```